# Graph API not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I just started working with Graph API and have it working to login, however not to do graph api calls.  I have set the delegate (i think), but it isn't calling back the delegate methods i implemented.  Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Profile.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FBRequest.h"
@interface HomeViewController : UITableViewController <FBRequestDelegate>
{
    Profile *profile;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;

@end
```

implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    profile = [[Profile alloc] initWithUserId:1];
    [profile refreshMatchesWithCallback:^ 
     {
             [self.tableView reloadData];
     }];   

    [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"me", appDelegate.facebook.accessToken] andDelegate:self];
    [[appDelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"erre");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what  I see - it looks like you haven't initialized your app delegate.

Something along the lines of :

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Your appDelegate variable has not been initialized - so is nil.

Note: I'm basing this on the assumption you haven't initialized the app delegate anywhere else.